# Strange Behaviour on Git Pull Causing: "Error Local Changes... Would Be Overwritten By Merge"

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I make some changes then run the usual commands:

```
git add -u
git commit -m 'some changes'
git pull
```

but I get errors such as

```
error: unable to create file 'new_file.py' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'file.py' (Permission denied)
```

so I run

```
sudo git pull
```

Then, I get the error in the title; 
when I run git status I see many new changes not staged for commit. I have to add the changes (which I didn't make and only appeared after the failed pull), and commit, before I can pull and merge.

What is going on here?

Comment: Did you get any merge conflict error?

Comment: I don't get a merge conflict error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on master branch. Revert all the changes which you got after git pull.  Then create local branch using below command

```
git checout -b temp_branch
```

Check if your commit is there in temp_branch. Now go to master pull the new changes (git pull). Once the pull is complete you can either cherry pick your commit.  If there is any merge conflict resolve it and continue the cherry pick.